# Vue select options based on condition

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following template for a dropdown:

```
<select v-model="selectedClient" class="stat-select text-u-c">
  <option disabled value="">Please select a Client</option>
  <option>{{}}</option>
</select>
```

...and I have a button `click`-handler that I want to populate the `<option>`s based on some condition:

```
if (Department == 'IT') {
  // select option values should be A,B,C
} else (Department == 'Finance') {
  // select option values should be X,Y,Z
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use Vue's [list rendering syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) with `v-for`:

```
<ELEMENT v-for="VARIABLE in ARRAY" :key="ITERATOR_ID">
```

In your case with `<option>`s, you would have something like this:

```
<option v-for="item in options" :key="item.id">{{item.label}}</option>
```

...where `options` is a data property, containing an array like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, label: 'A' },
  { id: 2, label: 'B' },
  { id: 3, label: 'C' },
]
```

If you want a different set of `<option>`s based on `Department`, you could set `this.options` to a different array accordingly, and the data binding will update the `<option>`s automatically:

```
methods: {
  getOptions() {
    const dept = this.Department;
    if (dept === 'IT') {
      this.options = [
        { id: 1, label: 'A' },
        { id: 2, label: 'B' },
        { id: 3, label: 'C' },
      ];
    } else if (dept === 'Finance') {
      this.options = [
        { id: 4, label: 'X' },
        { id: 5, label: 'Y' },
        { id: 6, label: 'Z' },
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    options: null,
    Department: null,
    selectedClient: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    getOptions() {
      this.selectedClient = null;
      if (this.Department === 'IT') {
        this.options = [
          { id: 1, label: 'A' },
          { id: 2, label: 'B' },
          { id: 3, label: 'C' },
        ];
      } else if (this.Department === 'Finance') {
        this.options = [
          { id: 4, label: 'X' },
          { id: 5, label: 'Y' },
          { id: 6, label: 'Z' },
        ];
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span>Department:</span>
    <input id="dept" type="radio" v-model="Department" value="IT">
    <label for="dept">IT</label>
    <input id="fin" type="radio" v-model="Department" value="Finance">
    <label for="fin">Finance</label>
    <button @click="getOptions">Get options</button>
  </div>

  <select v-model="selectedClient"  class="stat-select text-u-c">
    <option disabled value="">Please select a Client</option>
    <option v-for="item in options" :key="item.id">{{item.label}}</option>
  </select>
  
  {{selectedClient}}
</div>
```